# COM объект перестал работать PHP

Tags: php, com

Здравствуйте. На сервере стоял "Windows NT WEB2003 5.2 build 3790 (Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 2) i586" поменяли на "Windows NT WEB 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter Edition Service Pack 1) i586" и теперь в программе, который стоит в этом сервере, перестал работать заполнение документа Excel то есть выдает ошибку 500. Версия php, компоненты сервера все тот который стояла на старом сервере.

```
Код который работает в старом сервере:
$Excel = new COM( 'Excel.Application' ) or die("Unable to instanciate excel");
$Excel->AskToUpdateLinks = false;
$Excel->Visible = 0;
$Excel->DisplayAlerts = 0;
$Excel->Workbooks->Open( $file );

$cnt = $Excel->Sheets->Count();

for($ww=1; $ww<=$cnt; $ww++){
    $WorkSheet = $Excel->Worksheets($ww);
    $WorkSheet->activate;

    $LastCell = $WorkSheet->Cells->SpecialCells(11);
    $LastRow = $LastCell->Row;
    $LastCol = $LastCell->Column;

    for($i=1; $i<=$LastRow; $i++){
        for($j=1; $j<=$LastCol; $j++){
            $Cell = $WorkSheet->Cells( $i, $j );
            $Value = $Cell->Text;
            preg_match_all('/(%.*?%)/s', $Value, $matches);
            foreach($matches[0] as $match){
                if(in_array($match, array_keys($Params)))
                    $Value = str_replace($match, $Params[$match], $Value);
                else{
                    if(preg_match('/%date_priem_last_(.*?)%/s', $Value, $out)){
                        $days = $out[1];
                        list( $d2, $m2, $y2 ) = explode( '.', $Params['%date_priem_last%'] );
                        $Value = str_replace( $out[0], date("d.m.Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m2, ($d2+$days), $y2)), $Value );
                    }
                    else
                        $Value = str_replace($match, ' ', $Value);
                }
            }
            $Cell->Value = $Value;
        }
    }
}

$WorkSheet = $Excel->Worksheets(1);
$WorkSheet->activate;

$filename = realpath( tempnam( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/tmp', 'a' ) );
unlink( $filename );
$Excel->ActiveWorkbook->SaveAs( $filename );
$Excel->Quit();
$Excel = Null;

clearstatcache();

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $Arguments['template'] );
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0,pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: public");

$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
echo fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

unlink( $filename );
```

Может кто то подскажет какая проблема может быть? 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: установите сам `Excel` на сервер

Comment: На сервере стоит Microsoft office 2013.

Comment: стояла та же 2013-версия? сам файл создается? попробуйте сохранить сразу после создания пустым. локализуйте проблему где именно падает

Comment: там шаблоны стоять, вроде не может открывать шаблоны ($Excel->Workbooks->Open( $file ); после этого ошибка), раньше стоял 2003, когда увидел проблему опять поставил 2003, но тот же проблема.

Comment: да из open проблема

Comment: дак а чей `Excel.Application` теперь запускается, 2013 или 2003й, если их два на компе. названия должны как то отличаться ведь для 2003го

Comment: сейчас только 2013